# Очистка чата пользователя с телеграмм ботом от всех сообщений

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Мне нужно очищать приватный чат пользователя с Telegram-ботом от всех сообщений, или как-то пересоздавать для него чат. Допустим, ввожу команду `/start`, отображается текст с Inline кнопками. Когда пользователь нажимает на какую-либо из кнопок или пишет команду, с помощью `message.edit_text()`, меняется содержимое сообщения от бота. Но когда я ввожу повторно команду `/start`, мне нужно чтобы весь чат очищался, хотя бы локально для пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерный код, который должен помочь:

```
def start(update, context):
    # Получаем chat_id и user_id отправителя сообщения
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    user_id = update.effective_user.id

    # Удаляем все сообщения пользователя и бота в личном чате
    messages = context.bot.get_chat_history(chat_id)
    for message in messages:
        # Проверяем, что сообщение не является командой /start
        if message.text != '/start':
            context.bot.delete_message(chat_id, message.message_id)
```

```
В /start

    # Сохраняем id нового сообщения пользователя в контекст
    context.chat_data['user_messages'] = [message.message_id]
```

таким образом, используя `context` можно хранить в нем ид пользователя и при втором вызове `/start` чистить лс.